# How to Handle Previously Used actions in UITextField For TVOS

Tags: objective-c, swift3, uitextfield, tvos, apple-tv

I am facing problem with Textfield is having old assigned value when i click on edit focus its open default options in AppleTVos such as

Previous used

---

Clear All

AddNew

For Reference i have added the below image .when i press the Clear All or Add new its taken to me another page where already assigned Email ID exists on text field i would like clear at that moment .

Previously used words are working fine but where as when i tap on ClearAll or Add New i should take to Empty Email Text field , So i need the delegate action for Clear All /Add New Method .

For Reference Added below screen shot.

[image]

Thanks

Srinivasa Ladi

Comment: Please read how to put together a proper Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you want create a list of all previous values added by user, and, at the end of the list, two buttons "Clear all" and "Add new"? Did you tried using a UITableView?

Comment: Its default feature for Apple TV. when ever you tried to enter value it redirect to previously used options .  in which we will be having 3  options all previous values along with that Add new and clear All.

Comment: I would like to handle that action with delegate  right now the feature .